# sshpass - scp error - lost connection

Tags: connection, cygwin, runtime-error, scp, sshpass

Any idea why I'm getting this. I can successfully ping the server from my local machine. which sshpass is showing valid output and I'm using Cygwin64.

```
$ sshpass -p loriK0ba scp SSUA-HG.war SSUA-RCd.war loki12:/tmp/ARUNKS
lost connection
```

To install sshpass, I followed the following steps then, -V shows me valid output:

```
#       IMPORTANT: You need to have sshpass utility installed on your local machine.
#       ============================================================================
#       HOW to get sshpass:
#       STEPS: Run the following commands in Cygwin console window - This is a one time action.
#             a. cd /cygdrive/c
#             b. wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sshpass/sshpass/1.05/sshpass-1.05.tar.gz
#             c. tar -xvzpf sshpass-1.05.tar.gz
#             d. cd sshpass-1.05
#             e. sh configure
#             f. make install
#             g. which sshpass
#       ============================================================================
```

.

```
sh configure; sleep 5; make install; sleep 5; which sshpass
```

Version of sshpass is:

```
$ sshpass -V
sshpass 1.05 (C) 2006-2011 Lingnu Open Source Consulting Ltd.
This program is free software, and can be distributed under the terms of the GPL
See the COPYING file for more information.
```

PS: When I run sshpass with the following command, it doesnt' error out but also not creating giga.txt file on the target server (thus it's not reaching / doing anything). Same user (case sensitive) exist on both local box (where Cygwin is running) and on the target machine.

```
sshpass -p loriK0ba ssh -q loki12 'rm -rf /tmp/ARUNKS/* 2>/dev/null; mkdir /tmp/ARUNKS 2>/dev/null'
```

Comment: I bet this issue is due to Cygwin 64 on my Win7 64 machine .. rather than sshpass installed. I re-ran all the steps per the note, but still getting the error.

Comment: Thank you for the output from terminal! It worked for me on Win7 and I couldn't find how to install it.